# Tagged class with assignability to untagged default

Tags: typescript

I have a class for an error, which may or may not have some tag to identify what went wrong (a string). I thought it would be useful, if the potential values would be visible in a signature, e.g.:

```
function f(): 'success' | MyError<'invalid'|'timeout'>
```

This so far seems easy. However, the problem comes with the "or may not" part, with the capability of assigning any `MyError<T>` to a default `MyError`, and the necessity of an argument for the constructor. Logically, if the signature says "no additional info given", then any error originating from a lower level may be given, which may have additional info, and that info just never accessed.

My first attempt was to simply use `string` as a default, then assignment is no problem:

```
class MyError<T extends string = string> {
  info: T;
  constructor(init: T) { this.info = init; }
}
let a: MyError = new MyError<'something'>('something');
```

There are two issues with this approach:

- Any consumer can access `a.info`, even if it isn't intended as anything useful
- The constructor requires an argument, even when it's an error without any more info

The first could be somewhat fixed by patching an extra type on top:

```
type InfoError<T extends MyError> = string extends T['info'] ? Omit<T, 'info'> : T;

let b = new MyError<'something'>('something');
let c: InfoError<MyError> = b;
```

However, this makes more issues than it solves. Everything needs to be explicitly typed, so the signature is correct, when just returning `new MyError('completely useless')`, and it still needs an argument.

Isn't there something easier i overlooked?

---

Last bruteforce attempt (which i think works, emphasis on 'think'. In this context, 'works' means typesafe, although there are `any`-casts, as long as `__CompoundError` itself is never exported), snippet to collapse:

```js
class __CompoundError<T extends string> {
  tag: T;
  constructor(tag?: T) {
    if (tag === undefined) this.tag = '' as any;
    else this.tag = tag;
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(__CompoundError, 'name', {
  value: 'CompoundError',
  configurable: true,
});

type CompoundError<T extends string> = string extends T ? Omit<__CompoundError<T>, 'tag'> : __CompoundError<T>;

const CompoundError: {
    new <T extends string>(tag: T): CompoundError<T>;
    new (): CompoundError<string>
  } = __CompoundError as any;

// ################# tests #################

let generic = new CompoundError(); // don't need any argument for generic version
let a = new CompoundError('str'); // generic type inferred
let b: CompoundError<'str' | 'other'>;

// generic.tag // error, generic doesn't have property tag
a.tag; // ok

generic = a; // ok, can assign to generic version
b = a; // ok, can assign to more broad version

console.log(a.constructor.name); // 'CompoundError'

declare function f(): CompoundError<'str'>; // can use as a type
function g() { return new CompoundError('str'); } // can just return value and infer function type
```

A similar version to what i'll probably end up using afterall:

```js
class CompoundError {}

class CompoundErrorTagged<T extends string> extends CompoundError {
  constructor(public tag: T) { super(); }
}

// ################# tests #################

let generic = new CompoundError(); // don't need any argument for generic version
let a = new CompoundErrorTagged('str'); // generic type inferred
let b: CompoundErrorTagged<'str' | 'other'>;

// generic.tag // error, generic doesn't have property tag
a.tag; // ok

generic = a; // ok, can assign to generic version
b = a; // ok, can assign to more broad version

console.log(a.constructor.name); // 'CompoundErrorTagged'

declare function f(): CompoundErrorTagged<'str'>; // can use as a type
function g() { return new CompoundErrorTagged('str'); } // can just return value and infer function type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go here is to think of an error with no tag at all as a different type entirely.

```ts
class TaggedError<T extends string> {
  constructor(public info: T) { }
}

class UntaggedError {
  constructor(/* Other untagged error arguments? */) {}
}

type MyError<T extends string> = TaggedError<T> | UntaggedError;
```

Now `MyError<T>` includes the possibility that the error might actually be untagged. Typescript is going to protect you here, it won't let you access the `info` property until you determine if the error is tagged or untagged.

```ts
function f(): 'success' | MyError<'invalid' | 'timeout'>;

const result = f();

if (result === 'success') {
  // ... success!
}

// ERROR: Property info does not exist on type UntaggedError
console.log(result.info);

if ('info' in result) {
  console.log(`TaggedError<${result.info}>`);
} else {
  console.log('UntaggedError... I dunno what happened!');
}
```

If you don't like the `'info' in result` form of type narrowing, you can always write a typeguard.

```ts
function isTaggedError<T>(e: MyError<T>): e is TaggedError<T> {
  return 'info' in e;
}

if(isTaggedError(result)) { // type inference just works here
  console.log(`TaggedError<${result.info}>`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but one part is, that the consumer knows from the signature, what he is getting. Having to test, that `info` exists, when the signature already says it exists, is a bit odd. Maybe a `type MyError<T extends string> = string extends T ? UntaggedError : TaggedError<T>` would be better, but then i could also use `Omit<TaggedError<T>, 'info'>`, but there is an odd assignability problem i can't solve here. Also, everything needs to be typed explicitly, i can't just `return new MyError();` and let the inferrer handle the rest.

Comment: I understand the concerns you have, I think each is addressable. Even if you kept `info` as optional or giving it a dummy value, your consumer is still going to have to figure out if they should pay attention to the `info`. However, if you split the types, now they have a type safe, definitive way to determine if there's any extra info to be gained from the error. Also, you don't lose any explicitness since in this example `MyError` no longer has a constructor. You'll have to return a `TaggedError<T>` or `UntaggedError` explicitly.

Comment: I'll accept this, as it kept giving me the correct push towards not forcefully trying to unify the classes. That said, the important part is, that `TaggedError` should inherit from `UntaggedError`, so the assignment `declare let a: TaggedError; let b: UntaggedError = a` is guaranteed to work. I came to the conclusion, that some unified type (e.g. `MyType`) is just making things more tedious. I forgot about the basics. I'll also add my last attempt at brute-forcing this into the question, which i think works, but oh wow it's a bit of a mess.